# How to fully convert Ubuntu to Ubuntu Gnome (not just installing Gnome)?

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade, ppa

I've been using Ubuntu since 7.10 on a number of different computers. I'm currently using 13.10 on my home computer and 13.04 on my work computer. I prefer the Gnome 3 desktop experience and it's working great on my 13.04 computer. I recently switched to Gnome 3 from Unity back in 12.04 and have been upgrading with each official release. I did not upgrade my work computer due to a number of complications with Gnome 3 after upgrading to 13.10. I've tried the official Gnome PPA's and also completely purging Gnome and re-installing it (with and without PPA's, tried both ways). Still having issues.

That being said, I would like to switch to using a pure Ubuntu Gnome rather than Ubuntu with Gnome installed. I am hoping to avoid the conflicts I've been experiencing and wonder if there was a way to convert my existing Ubuntu install to be recognized as a Ubuntu Gnome install so that when I upgrade to 14.04 it will follow the full Ubuntu Gnome upgrade process rather than the regular Ubuntu process.

I realize I could "simply" (not really that simple) install Ubuntu Gnome on a freshly formatted computer, but I really would rather not have to go through that process if I can help it.

So, is it possible to modify my Ubuntu install in some way (PPA's, config files, something else?) to have it recognized as Ubuntu Gnome? Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

And when PC asks which display to use, select "gdm".

**Installing Ubuntu GNOME Applications:** Type these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-weather gnome-music gnome-maps cheese gnome-documents
```

This should do the trick. **This does not install GNOME on your desktop-it gives you the full Ubuntu GNOME Experience without installing a fresh OS.**

Comment: I have done this, but when upgrading it still goes through the default Ubuntu upgrade process (ex: 13.04 upgrade to 13.10) and it leaves me with conflicts between Unity settings and Gnome settings (and probably some other issues) after the upgrade.

Comment: ERROR: Unable to locate package ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Comment: My bad. There, this should work now.

Comment: @mason81 That is inevitable, since we're not removing Unity. And kamil, no matter how much you like GNOME 3, **it is always advisable to keep Unity installed since GNOME3 may not be up-to-the-mark.**

Comment: @MayukhNair so are you saying that I would have the same conflicts if I had installed Ubuntu Gnome originally rather than vanilla Ubuntu?

Comment: NOt at all. Ubuntu GNOME **completely gets rid of Unity.**

Comment: So you don't have any conflicts then. But installing Vanilla desktops results in conflict between GUIs. This is alright, and does not mess with your system.

Comment: @MayukhNair fair enough. So in addition to installing Gnome I also need to completely remove Unity in order to get the Ubuntu Gnome experience (I don't use unity at all). I would consider this, however I suspect that when I upgrade to 14.04 it would still use the Ubuntu (rather than Ubuntu Gnome) process and thus Unity would be back along with conflicts. So ultimately my best choice -- as big of a pain as it will be -- is to format and then install a fresh Ubuntu Gnome and wash my hands of this mess. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the best answer (and indeed at this time it is the only answer). I appreciate the commands you've added and I am sure they will be helpful to some wanting to try Gnome on Ubuntu. I still have concerns about conflicts with Unity and the upgrade process, but I do appreciate the feedback just the same. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome ;) . And did these commands work?

Comment: @MayukhNair -- yes, I had already run these commands previously and things were working find before I upgraded to 13.10. I ended up upgrading to 14.04 and I still have the same conflicts, so I'll probably be blowing everything away and just installing straight from a Ubuntu Gnome dvd. I've been upgrading this particular machine since 10.10, so I guess it's about time for a fresh install anyway.